# unable to open for write unix error: No such file or directory. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, sharp, avif

I'm trying to convert png to avif via Sharp, but I'm getting an error.

Code example

```
const image = sharp(`./images/img/original/image.png`)
    .avif({quality: 70, loseless: true})
    .toFile(`/images/img/avif/out.avif`)
```

Error

```
[Error: /images/img/avif/6znl4e0.avif: unable to open for write unix error: No such file or directory
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: The output directory `/images/img/avif/` likely doesn’t exist. Note that as input you use `./images/`, which is very different from the `/images/` in the output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharp doesn't create a directory if it doesn't exist, You should check if the directory exists, and create it (using fs, for example).

Here's an answer from : [Github](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1914)